# Social Security (USA) increase early?

Tags: united-states, social-security

I always thought that everyone's social security increase happened like mine, in January.  And in fact, that has always happened also for my wife.  Several web pages confirm that as the case, except that the SSI (not applicable to us) starts 30 December.

But today, my wife's social security statement (on the SSA website) says she is going to get the increase on 3 December!  I tried to check mine, but only got a completely blank page in the browser.

Anyone have an accurate explanation, or do I have to call SSA and be on hold for an hour?

Comment: The [official announcement](https://www.ssa.gov/cola/) says "January 2023". What exactly does it say on your wife's statement?

Comment: It literally says that the next payment before deductions will be an amount that is extremely close to 8.7 percent over the current.  And in the next line says what we already knew: that the next payment is 3 December.  I wish I had taken a screen shot, because now when we click "sign in," we get a completely blank window.

Comment: Let's see what the actual payment is then?

Comment: No doubt on 3 December, we'll know whether there was a bug in the SSA website that produced the wrong information.  I guess I'm impatient.  Maybe the blank screens are a hint that there is an error.

Comment: Is her birthday on the 1st day of the month? For historical processing reasons, social sec considers that day to be part of the _previous_ month, which affects eligibility date and presumably other processing.

Comment: No, not the first.  According to another SSA page, all SSI increases are paid the last day of December and all SS increases are _for_ December and paid in January.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Social Security Office, the exact timing of the increase depends on when in the month your birthday falls.
Some people get the higher amount already in December; others only in January.

Comment: It seems to be poor design of their website.  It literally says the next payment is the new amount and on the next line it says the next payment is 3 December.  But the letter they sent to her says the increase is FOR December and will be received 3 January.  The people who get SSI will see _that_ increase in December.

Answer (score 1):

Well, now she has the announcement by e-mail of the increase.  Apparently someone screwed up on coding that generated the web page.  It literally says the next payment is (new amount) and on the next line it says the next payment is 3 December. But the e-mail they sent confirms that the increase will be in the 3 January payment.